# Как убрать кнопку Start или Начать у телеграмм бота

Tags: java, telegram

При открытии чата у бота всегда появляется кнопка старт. Как убрать эту кнопку, чтобы не было понятно что это бот, а как будто открыл чат с человеком?
Знаю, что это реализовано у ботов, но нигде не нашел инфы по этому вопросу.

Comment: Возможно, что это невозможно:)

Comment: Это одна из базовых команд. Нет сведений о том, что её можно отключить. https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#global-commands

Answer (score 3):

Кнопку скрыть нельзя, это базовое поведение для того, чтобы начать работать с ботом.

Answer (score 0):

Путем долгих изысканий понял, что реализовано это не у ботов. А у аккаунтов для спама и автоответа. Всем спасибо за помощь